# How can I determine the smallest quotient for all general cases?

Tags: divisibility

If i have a big number, like:

$39486432$ or $485921157$

And they ask me, with what number when dividing it, is it left with less residue? If you take into account the exact divisors. I would not like to use brute force, is there a wonderful theorem or approach to this?

Graphically: $\frac{485921157}{n}$, get the $n$ with less residue, without take into account the $0$ residue.

Comment: The smallest non-zero remainder is $1$. Do you really want this? Then the answer is trivial.

Comment: I suspect you would be better served by asking a more detailed problem.  Little can be gathered by reading the Question in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably a good answer, for a large number $n$, is "Divide it by $n-1$; that'll give a remainder of 1, which is as small as possible while not being zero."

Thus in one of your examples, we have
$$
\frac{ 485921157}{ 485921156} = 1
\text
{with a remainder of $1$}.
$$

Comment: More generally, (for $n > 1$) the integers which give a remainder of $1$ are the factors of $n - 1$.

Comment: Good point, Travis --- thanks!